# what does import SomeSVG from 'img/someimage.svg?inline' means?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

what does this `?inline` after file extension do?
These SVGs are used as a react component then.

Comment: Do you know what Webpack loader you're using? Its probably a configuration for that. We would need to know which loader.

Answer (score 0):

> Inline SVG simply refers to SVG markup that is included in the markup
> for a webpage.

https://www.viget.com/articles/getting-started-with-inline-svg/